# check the permissions of a specified folder using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, win32-process

Is there any c++ program where you can input a folder path or a file name in order to display the system permissions specified on that folder or file (eg. full control,modify,read/write etc.) on a windows machine. I am not looking for reading/writing, I have to print all the permissions on that specified folder/file.

For example, this is the folder name/path:"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\desktop1" 
I have to print

1.full control

2.modify

3.read

according to the permissions on this folder.

Comment: Could you provide us with some sample code? That way, we can provide you more accurate answers

Comment: @m.r226 may have been onto something with their deleted answer. If they would fill it out, expand it from just a link to an MSDN page to something that will survive MSDN shuffling their links I think they'd have a decent answer.

Comment: i cant find anything on the internet. That is the problem

Comment: "the system permissions (eg. full control,modify,read/write etc.)" - that's not how it works on Windows. Files and folders have Access Control Lists (ACL's). These are tied to users and groups.

Comment: yes,need to use ACL to do that. please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp).

Example:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp> 
.
.

namespace fs=boost::filesystem;
int main(int argc,char * argv[]){    
    fs::path p(argv[1]);
    fs::file_status s = status(p);
    std::cout<<p<<" premissions: "<< p.permissions()<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Visual Studio you have, you can take advantage of the File System TS, which is slated for C++17, but appears in the experimental tree in recent VS versions, with VS2015 appearing to have the permissions component implemented.

File System TS: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

status() to get the information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/status

MSDN File System TS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx